# How to add two prometheus metrics together

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

If I query for one metric then I get a result `1`:

```
node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="active",type="simple"}
```

If I query for the same metric but with a different label then I get a result `0`:

```
node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="inactive",type="simple"}
```

But if I try to add them together then I get `no data`

```
node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="active",type="simple"} + node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="inactive",type="simple"}
```

But from reading https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/examples/#using-functions-operators-etc I'd expect my expression to work:

> If we have two different metrics with the same dimensional labels, we can apply binary operators to them and elements on both sides with the same label set will get matched and propagated to the output. For example, this expression returns the unused memory in MiB for every instance (on a fictional cluster scheduler exposing these metrics about the instances it runs):
>
> (instance_memory_limit_bytes - instance_memory_usage_bytes) / 1024 / 1024

- How do I add my two metrics together?
- What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the `ignoring` function for reasons that probably have to do with linear algebra but this is what you're looking for:

```
node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="active",type="simple"} * 4 + ignoring(state) node_systemd_unit_state{name="web.service",state="inactive",type="simple"} * 3
```

I found an example described in the prometheus docs about: [Vector matching](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching)

> One-to-one finds a unique pair of entries from each side of the operation. In the default case, that is an operation following the format vector1  vector2. Two entries match if they have the exact same set of labels and corresponding values. The ignoring keyword allows ignoring certain labels when matching, while the on keyword allows reducing the set of considered labels to a provided list:
>
> ```
> <vector expr> <bin-op> ignoring(<label list>) <vector expr>
> <vector expr> <bin-op> on(<label list>) <vector expr>
> ```
>
> Example input:
>
> ```
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{method="get", code="500"}  24
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{method="get", code="404"}  30
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{method="put", code="501"}  3
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{method="post", code="500"} 6
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{method="post", code="404"} 21
>
> method:http_requests:rate5m{method="get"}  600
> method:http_requests:rate5m{method="del"}  34
> method:http_requests:rate5m{method="post"} 120
> ```
>
> Example query:
>
> ```
> method_code:http_errors:rate5m{code="500"} / ignoring(code) method:http_requests:rate5m
> ```